# How to capture screenshot in selenium with specific resolution?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to capture a screenshot of the canvas element with specific resolution. I am using below snippet to capture the screenshot. this works but always takes a screenshot of resolution 1544px*638px. based on what (browser window or my window screen)is it taking a screenshot. I am using chrome browser. how can I modify my code below to take a screenshot of the resolution say 500 * 325 or so.

I have used set_window_size(500, 325) and I get screenshot of size 750 * 135

```
def capture_screenshot():
    driver = LiveLibrary.get_webdriver_instance()
    driver.set_window_size(500, 325) 
    canvas_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//canvas")
    result = canvas_element.screenshot_as_png
    with open('save.png', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(result)
```

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: The taken screenshot depends on your screen resolution... I believe you can't manipulate that. You can use OpenCV library to work-around this

Comment: by resolution do you mean size? or actual quality of image?

Comment: size (width and height)

Comment: have you tried using `PIL` to resize it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may resize the screenshot with [Image.resize](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize) from PIL. Like:

```
from PIL import Image
import io

    ...

    result = canvas_element.screenshot_as_png
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(result))
    imageResized = image.resize( (500,325), Image.ANTIALIAS) 
    with open('save.png', 'wb') as f:
        imageResized.save(f , format='PNG')
```

Comment: i have to use this image for comparison as well later.

Comment: if comparison takes place in the same python script, you may return the image from `capture_screenshot()`

Comment: why would you change the `quality` of Image (instead of the default 80)?

Comment: @wishmaster, thanks for noticing that, removed it, of course quality should not be set as png is a lossless format, my bad, I copypasted the save call without much thinking